# ReSharper C++ code analysis not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I've installed ReSharper C++ and I've enabled code analysis in the settings. The "Errors in Solution" window displays the message "No errors in solution", while the "Error List" window displays a bunch. According to [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html), C++ is supported for Solution-Wide analysis. Is there something I'm missing? Other than specified above, this is a fresh install of Visual Studio and ReSharper.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a static code analyzer? Which analyses, the code, that is compiling, for potential issues, while the "error list" shows you compile time errors? There isn't any point in running the static code analyzer on the code that doesn't even compile.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand, when does the "Errors in Solution" window display errors? Because any errors would cause the code to fail to compile, no?

Comment: Since I wasn't working with Resharper in C++ environment, I don't know if that Resharper code analyzer is just a static code analysis tool, and you didn't answer. Since as far as I can see, you are thinking about any error as "compilation error", which is exactly what it means - failure to compile. However, static code analyzer "error" is more like you have a bug that can/will cause a crash of your program (not to mention any other possible outcome).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius A quote from the page I've linked: "Solution-wide error detection of any compiler or runtime errors in the whole solution that lets you view the list of errors using the Errors in Solution Window window and navigate between these errors." It clearly notes any compiler or runtime errors, so I assume it isn't just a static code analysis tool. This is why I'm confused it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the bottom of the page you linked (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html), you'll see that feature is not supported for C++. Would love to see it though, I love this feature when working in C#.

Comment: I've since noticed this myself, hope to see it added in the future :)